# Is it possible to Include variable with URL in CURLOPT_URL?

Tags: php, facebook, variables, url, curl

I am storing the Facebook page ID in the variable pageID, and I want the Graph API to retrieve information from these IDs. I am trying to include the variable $pageId with the rest of the URL, however this does not return anything.

Would anyone suggest any alternatives, or whether I am doing something wrong?

```
  $pageId = substr($_POST["URL"], $pageIdPosition +1);
                        echo $pageId;
                        echo "<br />\n";
                        echo "<br />\n";
                        // create a new cURL resource
                            $ch = curl_init();

                            // set URL and other appropriate options
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://graph.facebook.com/" + $pageId);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

                            // grab URL and pass it to the browser
                            curl_exec($ch);

                            // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
                            curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Seems legit. Can you debug the request you make (the final value of the URL)? Maybe the `$pageId` variable doesn't has the value you think it should.

Comment: I printed the final value of the URL (the pageId) and it has the value it should.

Comment: I believe that you're trying to GET response from the API (and not to POST anything). The response is being returned by the `curl_exec` function. So: `$res = curl_exec($ch); var_dump($res);`.

Comment: The GET response should still get some JSON code, as I has tried entering the entire URL (without the variable), and the result is some JSON code. 

However I tried adding the code you have suggested and I got bool(false).

Comment: 1. Can you share the json string that is being returned if you use the entire URL? 2. If `false` is being returned that something indeed went wrong - try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`.

Comment: This is the json string returned with the entire URL "string(203) "{"id":"623952922","first_name":"Jessica","gender":"female","last_name":"Massa","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/jessica.massa.75","locale":"en_GB","name":"Jessica Massa","username":"jessica.massa.75"}"

Comment: With API v2 – use of which will become mandatory beginning of next month – you will need to pass an access token with that kind of API call (which is for a user profile, not a page btw., despite your variable being named otherwise) anyway.